# Is it possible to use one camera for two scenes?

Tags: javascript, three.js, scene, perspectivecamera

Hello :) I'm trying to render two different scenes. With a camera that should move following the same way simultaneously in the two renderer.

To explain what I want to do :
I want to render two different pointclouds in two differents scenes, but I want the cameras in the different scenes to move similarly in both scenes.

So I was wondering, how could I do that in an efficient way ?

I tried with two renderers, two scene, and one camera, but it seems it's not possible. I got this error after adding a sphere to each scene :
three.js:21528 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Am I forced to use two cameras ? or is it possible to do it in an other way ?
And is it also possible to use one same object and add it to two different scenes ? (it seems that it's not possible because, it removes the object from the first scene when I add it to an other).

Thanks for any help :D

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that a camera or a mesh object can only be assigned to one scene at any given time.  This is because "adding" (the method of assigning) creates a child:parent object relationship and a child can only have one parent at any given time.

Theoretically you could have a single camera and move it repeatedly from one scene to another and render each scene only when it contains the camera.  You could also shuttle one or more mesh objects between scenes.  But I don't know how well this would work particulalry if you have lots of things shuttling between scenes and you are also looking for a high frame rate.

A safer approach would be to make one camera for each scene and then make sure that the two cameras move in the same way - i.e. synchronize their .position and .rotation values before rendering each frame.  Likewise for any mesh objects that you wish to appear in both scenes - create multiple copies of each mesh object and synchronize any changes in their .position, .rotation or other properties.

Answer (score 0):

A camera does not have to be added to the scene, so the camera can be used to render multiple scenes. The only time a camera must be added to the scene is if the camera has a child -- a child light, for example.

A single renderer can be used to render different scenes.

An object, such as a mesh or point cloud, has only one parent, so it can only be added to one scene at a time.

three.js r.75